# DOM object not referenced

Tags: javascript, oop, dom, reference

I have a simple class that has a parent element, and i store it's child element progress, but when I add to the child element nothing happens

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(element) {
    this.elem = element;
    this.child = this.elem('.child');
    this.fill();
  }
  fill() {
    this.elem.innerHTML += '<span class="child2"></span>';
  }
  update(val) {
    this.child.style.width = val + '%';
  }
}
```

When I call the update function nothing happens. If I print the child element I see that it has a style of `val%` but I don't see it "update" in the DOM.

It's like it is copying the object and not storing the reference.

**BTW:**
Also this works ok `this.elem.querySelector('.child').style.width = val + '%';`

Also tried with `children[0]` also won't work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you somewhere use `innerHTML` in your code? And it would help to show us your markup as well. That sounds to me like the problem newbies have when using `node.innerHTML += `.

Comment: Have checked the value of this.ch in the update function ?

Comment: No, I don't copy the markup, I only work with the DOM.
Markup is simple: `<div class="parent"><span class="child"></span></div>`

Comment: can you provide a link/example/fiddle that replicates the error

Comment: WAIT I GOT IT... @Thomas is right.. I have a code that appends stuff to parent!

Comment: @Thomas updated the code so you can answer.. I really forgot about this function. So this is why my childtree was broken.. I will do it  appendChild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple utility that converts markup to a documentFragment to push around.

```
var dummy = document.createElement('div');
function fromHTML(markup){
    dummy.innerHTML = markup;
    for(var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), fc; fc = dummy.firstChild;)
        frag.appendChild(fc);
    return frag;
}
```

so instead of `node.innerHTML += someMarkup;` better do `node.appendChild( fromHTML(someMarkup) )`

in your case

```
fill() {
    this.elem.appendChild( fromHTML('<span class="child2"></span>') );
}
```

or in this simple case, avoid the markup at all:

```
fill() {
    var child = document.createElement('span');
    child.className = "child2"; //avoid enumerated classes/valriables/everything
    this.elem.appendChild( child );
}
```

Comment: I really didn't see the function add the start.. When I search innerHTML i found it.. Thanks for the function but the markup is simple so I will simply use `createElement` and `appendChild`.. Thank you for remaining me!!!

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter said, this is likely to be linked to the use of .innerHTML on a parent node or the node itself. The reason behind this is when you use .innerHTML, JavaScript modifies the DOM and "rebuilds" it inside the node innerHTML. This will release all existing handles to the existing nodes. This means all listeners and references will get lost when you update the innerHTML.

Considering appending instead of editing the innerHTML and this will solve your issue.